# How do I create a random item spawner with no repeats?

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I am currently working on a rogue-like game in GameMaker Studio 2 and i would like to have an item spawner where no items are repeated.

I have tried multiple different ideas of what i think would work, such as giving items and id variable and only spawning items which hasn't had it's id called, although it doesn't seem to work.

The code I have right now is basic, but that is because it's the only way I've been able to spawn an item, there is repeating items with what i have and i would like to stop that from happening.

Here is the Create code of the object:

```
// Items
var items = choose(
obj_homing,
obj_tracking,
obj_bounce,
obj_double_xp,
obj_shotgun,
obj_orbit,
obj_firefaster,
obj_scattershot,
obj_damageboost,
obj_explosive
);


instance_create_layer(x, y, "Items", choose(items));
```

I haven't had any actually crashes in the game, although the errors i have faced are multiple of the same object spawning twice when i would like items to not repeat.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to modify the items array after each call to remove the spawned item, and re-initialize it as full only at the start of each game or when the array is empty.

The problem I'm seeing in looking through the [Game Maker Language Documentation](https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/3_gml_overview/10_arrays.html) is that I cannot find a way to delete an object from an existing array and resize the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're placing `choose` on both defining the var, and when creating the layer.

Now, I don't know exactly what `choose` does, but I assume it's choosing randomly a selection from the array.

So `Items` would only return a single chosen item from the array, maybe it's better to remove the choose function from the `Items`, and only decide that when creating the object.

So the `Items` should become an array:

```
var items = [
obj_homing,
obj_tracking,
obj_bounce,
obj_double_xp,
obj_shotgun,
obj_orbit,
obj_firefaster,
obj_scattershot,
obj_damageboost,
obj_explosive
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the random instance in a variable, then when you create a random instance, check if equals to the instance that you have created previously, and if it is, call again the function until the previous instance is different from the new generated instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spawn every item only once, how about changing the current spawned object in the array to "noone".

And at every spawn cycle, you would check, if the selected item is noone and if so, select the next item (array[i++]).

Also do not forget to randomize the seed, somewhere in the beginning of your game with randomize().